# iOS - determine what screen appears first in project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this might be a very basic question. But I am new to iOS.
I am building ontop of an existing project I found.I would like to add a scene( screen) which I would like to pop up before the main screen shows. I have tried many things,  but no matter what I do, the first screen which pops up is the main screen.

Because I am new, please provide a detailed explanation.

And i am using a storyboard, i am not using a nib file which i would like to appear first.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you have tried so far (a piece of code)? It doesn't matter if it's not working.

Comment: in my appdelegate i used the following code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Storyboard, just select the view controller and enable *Is initial view controller* option.

[image]